# Yii: Corrupted image in CCaptcha

Tags: php, yii, php-gd

I have a trouble with the CCaptcha widget. Image is corrupted. Headers are looks right. When I tried to list an image as a text, I didn't find any text inclusions, it's looks like as a usual PNG content.

When I created an another webapp on the same framework instance, CCaptcha works correctly, but  in my first webapp have a trouble.

In my case GD library is used. Access filter is not used.

Comment: 'Looks like usual content', but did you save it to disk and view?

Comment: Yes, did. XnView throws an error when I tried to open this file. Then I opened file with Notepad++ and saw this "usual content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd found an error. It was a space before PHP open tag in top of base controller file. And now the bug is fixed.